# Typescript: Is there a way to use variables in a template literal type value?

Tags: typescript, types

I'd like to pass variables into a template literal type value, but [I can't seem to get it to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigIjmqAfdAjNAKEIEsA7YCBAMzgGNoAxAe2agG8AbOPCTgLigADACTt4CAL5QAFGLIBXALa8pASiGTidZmQDOwKAA9BLNqi48%20gjLIDMatJIDcUAPRuo1chG26DUEogEoISKPhozoQ6%20oZBAHLKgooqVOF2UTEBIKas4Za8AsJiQRLScuwJypIaLu6eVAjMCHpAA) (you can play with the following example here). Is this possible?

```
type Bar = "a" | "b"

interface Foo {label: `${Bar} (${number})`}

const x: Foo = {label: "a (3)"}; // fine

const myBar: Bar = "b";
const myNum: number = 3;
const y: Foo = {label: `${myBar} (${myNum})`}; // errors
```

Is there any way of getting `y` to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript 4.1 introduced [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) as well as the ability to infer such types for template literal expressions... but only, as you noticed, via a `const` assertion:

```
const y: Foo = { label: `${myBar} (${myNum})` } as const; // okay
```

This was implemented [microsoft/TypeScript#40707](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40707), which was merged before the release of TS4.1.

---

It does seem reasonable to want template literal expressions assigned to `const` variables to *automatically* be inferred as template literal types without needing an explicit `as const` anywhere.  After all, that's how string and numeric literals behave already:

```
let bStr = "b"; // uses let, so bStr is widened:
// let bStr: string

const bLit = "b"; // uses const, so bStr is a string literal, no "as const" required:
// const bLit: "b"
```

In fact, it seems *so* reasonable that, after TS4.1 was released, this exact change was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#41891](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41891) and merged, as you can see if you use TS4.2-beta:

```
const y: Foo = {label: `${myBar} (${myNum})`};  // okay
```

[Playground link, TS4.2 beta](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigIjmqAfdAjNAKEIEsA7YCBAMzgGNoAxAe2agG8AbOPCTgLigADACTt4CAL5QAFGLIBXALa8pASiGTidZmQDOwKAA9BLNqi48+gjLIDMatJIDcUAPRuo1chG26DUEogEoISKPhozoQ6+oZBAHLKgooqVOF2UTEBIKas4Za8AsJiQRLScuwJypIaLlDunswA1nAgQA)

---

**UNFORTUNATELY**, #41891 was a breaking change; real-world code using perfectly serviceable `string`-typed template literal expressions would suddenly start seeing strange types and possibly even errors.

In the TypeScript design meeting on Jan 21, 2021 (see [microsoft/TypeScript#42589](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42589)) this breakage and weirdness was discussed.  Apparently it was decided that automatically inferring template literal types would go too far.  After all, not every `const` variable is inferred to be as narrow as possible, and if you want narrower inference you can use `as const`:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
// const arr: number[]

const constArr = [1, 2, 3] as const;
// const constArr: readonly [1, 2, 3]

const obj = { a: "hello", b: "goodbye" };
// const obj: { a: string; b: string; }

const constObj = { a: "hello", b: "goodbye" } as const;
// const constObj: { readonly a: "hello"; readonly b: "goodbye"; }
```

So it was reverted in [microsoft/TypeScript#42588](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42588) and merged on or around Feb 3, 2021.  And thus your code that yields an error in TS4.1 will still be in error in TS4.2 (unless yet another reversal happens I guess):

[Playground link, TS4.2-dev.20210207](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20210207#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigIjmqAfdAjNAKEIEsA7YCBAMzgGNoAxAe2agG8AbOPCTgLigADACTt4CAL5QAFGLIBXALa8pASiGTidZmQDOwKAA9BLNqi48+gjLIDMatJIDcUAPRuo1chG26DUEogEoISKPhozoQ6+oZBAHLKgooqVOF2UTEBIKas4Za8AsJiQRLScuwJypIaLlDunlQIzEhwAOZw5ACExEA)

---

Oh well.  If you want template literal expressions to be inferred as template literal types, you will just need to use a `const` assertion.  Maybe in the future this will change, but for now I suppose we must automatic template literal inference as a failed/aborted experiment.  What a journey!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigIjmqAfdAjNAKEIEsA7YCBAMzgGNoAxAe2agG8oAbOPCLgFxQABgBJ28BAF8oACnFkArgFs+0gJTCoU4nWZkAzsCgAPISzapOPPoPRw5AZnVYpAbigB6T1GrkIuvpGUMogkkKSKPhoboR6hsahAHIqQkqqVFGOsfHBIOasUda8-EJi7KGSMvIVICnKUpraUHAGULnAsYRcEMZ4AMrASKhoBLHe3L1QA0NCRgjkAObEcUF9ADIkxiNjhBMd05vAQqNEqwktCMNQANoAjAA0UABMT44AuuM+B4gIaSpqG7vQIXDoAQSuUXuT1eUA+LTaHS+7TWKISEL+UAQEDgABN9FwQLdHi83sDzsFmHgAFZFFonAAW-C4zDQTzwJ0WrFxeBAEFcyIOVOpQk4cDmQyWHg5UHmUu0IOCHQA8jS6eL0EyuCy2dNOdzefzmq00UZBaiVTTRVicfiyIT6ZrmayPNi8QSiTK0FzmDy+TFtEA)

Answer (score 1):

As you already discovered, you can type it by using `as const`:

```
const y: Foo = {label: `${myBar} (${myNum})` as const}
```

The reason is that by using `as const`, TypeScript will narrow the type from `string` to the the actual template literal type. If you look at the label without `as const`, the inferred type will be `string`, which is not assignable to `${Bar} (${number})` (surrounded by backticks, which are a pain in inline markdown code):

```
const l1 = `${myBar} (${myNum})` // inferred type: string
```

If you use `as const`, the type gets narrowed to `b (${number})` (with backticks), which is assignable:

```
const l2 = `${myBar} (${myNum})` as const // inferred type: `b (${number})`
```

The `${number}` in the type appears because of the explicit `number` signature in `const myNum: number = 3`. If you use `const myNum = 3`, the inferred type becomes `b (3)` (surrounded by backticks).

Answer (score 0):

This gets it to compile, but I don't understand why I need to do it:

```
const z: Foo = {label: `${myBar} (${myNum})` as const}; // fine
```

I'll accept this as the answer if nobody else wants to chime in and explain.